# android Audio Recording

Tags: android

I want to Record audio but with some background images in out put file.

i tried normal recording function of android but,there out put file in only blank with    audio. but i want to add some images to that audio file,how can i do this one.

pls help me

Comment: Do you want album art, or du you want to show some images while the recorded music is playing?

Comment: show images while the recorded music is playing

Comment: Where do you want to display this image?

Comment: After Audio is recorded it is saved in sdcard,when we play that XXX.3gp file in some player it showing blank screen.but i want to show some image on that place

Comment: Then you need to look into how to add album art

Comment: can u post some sample code to add album art to .3gp file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place the image you want to display in the same folder with exact filename: "AlbumArt.jpg" the image will be shown